# Incorrect URL on Wordpress using Docker

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I've a pretty simple setup using Wordpress and Docker, with a `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: on-failure
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - ./backend/wordpress/wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
      - ./backend/wordpress/.htaccess:/var/www/html/.htaccess
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: ${WORDPRESS_DB_HOST}
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: ${WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX}
      WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA:
        define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true );
        define('WP_HOME','${WORDPRESS_URL}:${NGINX_EXTERNAL_PORT}');
        define('WP_SITEURL','${WORDPRESS_URL}:${NGINX_EXTERNAL_PORT}');


  nginx:
    build: ./backend/nginx
    links:
      - wordpress
      - phpmyadmin
    ports: 
      - ${NGINX_EXTERNAL_PORT}:80
    volumes:
      - "./backend/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
```

And this is my `nginx.conf` file:

```
upstream docker-wordpress {
    server wordpress;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name admin.example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_read_timeout 3600;
            proxy_pass http://docker-wordpress;
        }
    }
```

Everything seems to work correctly till I try to sort my Wordpress posts by name or slug or whatever field you want, and not only when I sort but also when I try to go to a 2nd page. Instead of getting something like:

`http://admin.example.com:5000/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=artista&orderby=title&order=asc`

I get my upstream name on the links, like this:

`http://docker-wordpress/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=artista&orderby=title&order=asc`

As I said, everything else works fine, and after taking a look at my site configuration I see that both Wordpress URL and Site URL are:

`http://admin.example.com:5000`

Which I believe it's correct, any idea what could be wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Could be because wordpress is using the Host coming from the request header and that you are missing a `proxy_set_header Host $host;` in your location to allow that to work. https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/#passing-request-headers

Comment: Thanks! I can't try it now but I'll try this! Makes sense

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! Actually your solution was partially correct, as I needed to add this:  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

Comment: Feel free to make that your answer and mark your own answer as the accepted one, as it can help others in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What worked finally was to adding a `proxy_set_header` directive to my `nginx.conf` file:

`proxy_set_header Host $http_host;`

Comment: note that you can set the host to an arbitrary domain inside the `location` if your machine hosts multiple sites